# Disable Parent Menu Item Fails in Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm self-taught when it comes to web design and so I really am stuck here because I don't have the framework for understanding the problem.  My website (sealinesd.com) is OK EXCEPT the parent links should be disabled AT ALL TIMES.  Right now it works like this:

-- when the regular non-responsive menu is up, the parent links are disabled thanks to the plugin I use (code below).

-- when you hover on the non-responsive menu and the parents are disabled, and THEN you make the browser smaller, the responsive items you hovered on before are still disabled.

-- when you go straight to the responsive menu without first hovering on the parents in non-responsive mode, the parent links are NOT disabled.

I have very little knowledge of jquery and DOM so I was unable to fix the plugin.  I tried to target the mean-menu (used in responsive mode) and use document.ready to make sure it wasn't executing too early, or something, but neither worked for me.  Please advise.  I thank you kindly in advance.

The code for the plugin I use to disable parent links is right below.

Plugin Name: Advanced Disable Parent Menu Link
Description: A plugin which allows you to disable parent menu link.
Author: Kapil Chugh
Plugin URI: http://kapilchugh.wordpress.com/
Version: 1.0

```
  add_action('wp_footer', 'advanced_disable_parent_menu_link');

  function advanced_disable_parent_menu_link () {
    wp_print_scripts('jquery'); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (jQuery("ul li.page_item:has(ul.children)").length > 0) {
        jQuery("ul li.page_item:has(ul.children)").hover(function () {
          jQuery(this).children("a").removeAttr('href');
          jQuery(this).children("a").css('cursor', 'default');
          jQuery(this).children("a").click(function () {
            return false;
          });
        });
      } else if (jQuery("ul li.menu-item:has(ul.sub-menu)").length > 0) {
        jQuery("ul li.menu-item:has(ul.sub-menu)").hover(function () {
          jQuery(this).children("a").removeAttr('href');
          jQuery(this).children("a").css('cursor', 'default');
          jQuery(this).children("a").click(function () {
            return false;
          });
        });
      }
    </script> <?php
  }
```

I tried this code too and it didn't work.  I'm frustrated.  Don't know how to target that damn responsive menu.

```
wp_print_scripts('jQuery'); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery("nav.mean-nav > li:has(ul.children)").length > 0) {
        jQuery(".mean-nav > ul > li:has(ul.children)").hover(function () {
            jQuery(this).children("a").click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
            jQuery(this).children("a").css('cursor', 'default');
          }
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about the menu items that are actually dropdowns?

Comment: The "services" and "specials" parents should have click events set to false so you can't open them.  The child items "small business", etc SHOULD be clickable.  Thanks for your quick response, btw.  Let me know if you need more info.  I could possibly give you the login to my dev subdomain so you can experiment if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your site. It appears to be built from a template that has created its own responsive functionality.

Personally, I would suggest that you look into using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to build your own pages. Bootstrap is extremely easy to implement once you [understand the 12 column grid system](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/).

Bootstrap has responsive menus with dropdowns like this all rolled in out of the box and it works great, [see this example](http://www.bootply.com/a2ytBOvJZ5)

You could easily duplicate the look of your template using bootstrap in very little time and there are TONS of resources online to help you.

Anyway, that said, if you want to to stop a click on a link from navigating to the link's href location you can use `.preventDefault();` like this:

```js
// prevent navigation when clicking links with the class preventDefault
$(document).on('click', '.preventDefault', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
// just to show that other events still make it through
$('#test').click(function(){
    $('#result').append('click detected<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com" class="preventDefault" id="test">Click this link</a><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Where were you when I first had this built lol.  Ya, Bootstrap sounds great.  I will check that out, for sure.  I'm gonna go try to implement the prevent default thing.  I did read about that but somehow didn't connect the dots.  I'll post back later tonight.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: OK, I tried that but I don't know if I did it right.  It didn't work.  I don't even know if that's the issue: like I said, it does work if you target the parents before changing to responsive view.  As long as you don't change the page or refresh, the links are disabled.  Why is the responsive menu not being targeted by my plugin, is the issue, I think. The code I tried is above in my question.